# Why does one need to give the kiddush wine to a minor when saying Kiddush in shul?

Tags: halacha, shabbat, synagogue, kiddush

[O.C. 269:1](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.269.1?lang=bi) (Sefaria translation in English):

> It is the custom to recite Kiddush in the synagogue, however, the one
>   who recites does not taste the wine of Kiddush but gives it to a minor
>   to taste **because Kiddush is recited at the place where the meal is
>   eaten.** From the outset this custom was established for the sake of
>   [communal] guests who eat and drink in the synagogue, so that they may
>   fulfill their obligation. And today, even though [communal] guests do
>   not eat and drink in the synagogue, the custom remains.

Why are we concerned about giving the wine to a child? If the person making Kiddush in shul does not fulfill his obligation of saying Kiddush because it is not said where the meal is, what would be the problem by his drinking the wine? He would still need to make Kiddush when he went home! Is there some other prohibition or restriction that I'm not seeing, here?

Comment: Why should he be allowed to eat before kiddush?

Comment: @DoubleAA If that's the only or main reason, then please make your 1st comment an answer. See my last sentence in the question.

Answer (score 5):

[Mishnah Berurah 269:2](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Berurah.269.2?lang=bi) explains that since the *chazzan* does not fulfill his *kiddush* obligation (as he is not eating his meal in the synagogue) he can’t drink the wine, because it is forbidden to eat or drink anything before *kiddush*. (This prohibition is discussed in [Shulchan Aruch Orach Chaim 271:4](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.271.4?lang=bi).)